# TP-Link USB wireless adapter keep losing data every several minutes without disconnecting?

Tags: networking, wireless, atheros, tp-link

I have a weird problem when I use my USB wireless adapter TP-Link `TL-WN722N` V1.9 with atheros`AR9271` after a random time it's suddenly losing data without even disconnecting is there any possible solution?

I'm running Desktop Ubuntu 21.04 and I tried some online solutions like blacklisting the `ar9271` and adding some options into `/etc/modprobe.d/ath9k_htc.conf` like `options ath9k_htc 11n_disable=1` & `options ath9k_htc nohwcrypt=1` but nothing happened :(

Comment: First what are you running? What version of Ubuntu? Desktop or Server? What troubleshooting have you done so far?

Comment: I'm running Desktop ubuntu 21.04 and I tried some online solution like blacklisting the ar9271 and adding some option into  /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k_htc.conf like "options ath9k_htc 11n_disable=1" & "options ath9k_htc nohwcrypt=1" but nothing happened :(

Comment: You need to add that to the question not just as a comment.

Comment: Thx I will do that :)

Comment: Pleasr add results for  `iwconfig` to the question

Answer (score 3):

Your wireless may be dropping because of power management; that is, the feature where the card partially powers down to save battery power during periods of inactivity and then, ideally, powers back up seamlessly when activity resumes. Let's disable power saving to see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*
```

Your wireless may be dropping because the channel to which it was connected has suddenly changed.

Please check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred.

Your wireless may be dropping because there are two wireless access points with the same name and password. This is typical when you have a 2.4 gHz segment and a 5 gHz segment of the same router. Your wireless may be roaming, looking for a better connection. If this is the case, I suggest that you rename the access points; something like myrouter2.4 and myrouter5.

After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?