# Internal dropouts problems

Tags: networking, network-manager

How can I troubleshoot the internal dropouts? WiFi drops out once few minutes. Few days before the problem started I had some cables for my internet changed by the ones I have a internet contract with. I got in contact with them but they didn't identified anything wrong. Could it be because of the PC?
I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

nmcli device wifi list:

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID                  MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  
        DC:53:7C:99:94:D9  UPC22C7FAD            Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  97      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2 
*       6C:A4:D1:4F:DE:A0  DIGI_4fdea0           Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  75      ▂▄▆_  WPA2      
        DC:53:7C:99:94:FE  UPC22C7FAD            Infra  36    405 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2 
        D4:B1:10:50:2C:E8  DIGI-hTdF             Infra  10    130 Mbit/s  39      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        EA:C3:2A:86:B9:67  --                    Infra  8     195 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2      
        D8:32:14:F0:C8:01  Tenda_F0C800          Infra  2     270 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        E4:C3:2A:86:B9:67  TP-Link_B967          Infra  8     195 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 
        DC:F8:B9:D0:96:E9  DIGI_d096e9           Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        34:2C:C4:38:93:56  Magic beauty salon 2  Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        00:5F:67:15:69:34  TP-LINK_51E2_2.4GEXT  Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2      
        80:8C:97:75:71:01  DIGI-24-757101        Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  25      ▂___  WPA2      
        90:55:DE:04:9D:18  DIGI_049d18           Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA2      
        D4:B7:09:F9:B0:84  DIGI_f9b084           Infra  3     130 Mbit/s  17      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 
        7C:8B:CA:A5:EE:0E  NELIAN                Infra  1     270 Mbit/s  14      ▂___  WPA2
```

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295

Comment: Nevermind, I found the solution. Thanks for help anyway.