# Why 802.11n does not work with Wireless-AC 9560?

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

WIFI works only when I add: `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless#iwlwifi

I need to use `802.11n`, so I tried to comment line `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`, restart system, WIFI does not work and `dmesg` still prints:
(MAC address was the same and I replaced it by XX.)

```
[   57.556282] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[   57.561958] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   57.613865] wlo1: authenticated
[   57.618280] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   57.722239] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 2/3)
[   57.826210] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 3/3)
[   57.934293] wlo1: association with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX timed out
[   65.558758] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[   65.565087] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   65.627537] wlo1: authenticated
[   65.634256] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   65.738333] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 2/3)
[   65.850198] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 3/3)
[   65.974282] wlo1: association with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX timed out
[   78.401729] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
[   78.406747] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   78.477221] wlo1: authenticated
[   78.478235] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[   78.582448] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 2/3)
[   78.690357] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 3/3)
[   78.798380] wlo1: association with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX timed out
```

and system cannot connect to the router. So `802.11n` still cannot work properly?

**System**: Ubuntu 20.04 with all updates
**WIFI card**: Wireless-AC 9560
**Router**: TP-Link Archer C6 (HW: Archer C6 v2.0, Firmware: 1.3.7 Build 20220613)

**Router settings**:
Security: WPA/WPA2-Personal
Version: Auto | WPA-PSK | WPA2-PSK -- tried all
Encryption: TKIP | AES -- tried both
Mode: "802.11 b/g/n mixed" | "802.11 n only" -- tried both
Channels width: auto
Channel: auto
The router was always restarted after the change.

**Computer settings**:
Security: WPA/WPA2-Personal

Connection from Windows 10 from another notebook works perfectly in 802.11n.

Additional info: Sometimes `dmesg` shows: `iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0xc040071b` System is disconnected from the network and system shows me a password dialog. Confirm password, network connection is established and works again.

Comment: Does your 80211n use the 5GHz band?  AC only uses 5GHz, but n may be on the 2.4GHz.

Comment: 5GHz is disabled on AC, so only 2.4GHz.

Comment: "MAC address replaced by XX" Are they, in every case, the exact same MAC address? Have you tried my troubleshooting steps here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295

Comment: Is your computer using WPA2 or WPA3? What is the router set for... WPA2 or WPA3, or WPA2+WPA3? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I answered to the post

Comment: @t0m The proper setting for the router is WPA2-AES. What channels are the two networks set for?  What are the wireless network's names? How long is the passphrase, and are there any special characters in it? Is the firmware in the router Archer C6(US)_V2_210226 (for a V2 router)? https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/archer-c6/

Comment: @t0m If you need help discovering what version router see https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/46/

Comment: @heynnema: I do not understand: "What channels are the two networks set for?" I used only 1 network. Channels info, HW + SW version of router added to the post.

Comment: @t0m It looks like you've answered most, but not all, of my questions from my previous comment. Please review. First things first, you need to update the firmware on the router.

Comment: @t0m Just curious... any particular reason that you're not using the 5Ghz band?

Comment: Same here with Wireless-AC 9260 and Archer C6 router: 5 Ghz works with frequent disconnects, and 2.4 Ghz only works with `11n_disable=1`, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Please see my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295