# WiFi keeps dropping, internal Intel adapter to AT&T Netgear modem, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

This is an insidious problem that is driving me nuts, and I have run out of skill.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Chuwi laptop with Intel 9461 wireless chip. Works flawlessly when connected to most WiFi, including my T-Mobile Pixel in hotspot mode, and the household Netgear WAP.

When I connect to the AT&T hotspot (Netgear MR1100) using WPA2-PSK, I get periodic disconnects/reconnects.

`journalctl -u NetworkManager` reveals the following:

```
Jan 14 16:45:06 Biscayne NetworkManager[954]: <warn>  [1642196706.3760] sup-iface[0x563fc2a5e920,wlo2]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Jan 14 16:45:06 Biscayne NetworkManager[954]: <info>  [1642196706.4092] device (wlo2): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Jan 14 16:45:06 Biscayne NetworkManager[954]: <info>  [1642196706.4093] device (p2p-dev-wlo2): supplicant management interface state: completed -> disconnected
```

for each time the connection drops. It then immediately scans and re-connects.

When I connect through the aforementioned Netgear WAP, the connection ultimately ends up at the very same AT&T MR1100. And if I plug in my ALFA wireless adapter via USB, I can stay connected directly to the very same MR1100. These disconnects only occur between the on-board Intel 9461 and the MR1100 directly.

`dmesg|grep iwl` shows the following:

```
[    5.694167] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: loaded firmware version 46.4d093a30.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.702677] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    5.776285] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9461, REV=0x318
[    5.828964] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: base HW address: f8:e4:e3:98:99:eb
[    5.877346] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.009380] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0 wlo2: renamed from wlan0
[   11.408323] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
[ 8852.250007] iwlwifi 0000:00:0c.0: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
```

My firmware is up to date (amd64 1.187.25).

I'm not sure what to look at or try next.

Comment: Please try a terminal command: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi lar_disable=Y` Does it help?

Comment: That seems to have changed the behavior. I am still getting disconnects, but now they are Reason 3.

Comment: May we see? `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I included that output in my OP.

Comment: I don't see any disconnects with reason 3 above. If you have administrative privileges over the MR1000, I suggest that you try my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295

Comment: OK, I followed all the recommendations from that post. Still getting a reason 4 disconnect. Here's the output from sudo dmesg | grep iwl: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mtKYDQ6Vhy/