# Extremely slow wifi on Ubuntu 20.04 after standard solutions, 18.04 is fine

Tags: 20.04, wireless, thinkpad

I have a clean Ubuntu 20.04 install on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon. I am running the kernel 5.13.0-28-generic. The wifi is extremely slow, making e.g. Zoom impossible, dropped calls, total loss of connectivity. With a speed test I get values of 7 Mbps Download, 5 Mbps Upload (and often much worse) while a different Thinkpad (X390) running Ubuntu 18.04 and sitting next to the X1 gets 52 Mbps Download, 44 Mbps Upload from the same home Wifi and the same speedtest. I even booted the computer with a USB stick under 18.04 (kernel 5.4.0-84-generic) and got 53 Mbps download, 37 Mbps Upload on the same computer!!

I read through similar questions and tried all solutions I could find.

1. I have disabled the 802.11n protocol adding `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1` to `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` -- No effect.
2. I have disabled power management by editing `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and changing the value from 3 to 2. I confirm by `iwconfig` that power management is off. No effect.
3. I have edited `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and changed hosts to `hosts: files dns` -- No effect.
4. In desperation I have edited `etc/gai.conf` and uncommented the line `Precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` -- No Effect.
5. Also, `backport_iwlwifi_dkms`is not installed.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Any ideas?

EDIT: Output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`

```
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0070]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Have you tried my troubleshooting steps here? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295

Comment: Yes, I have, thanks. It's not power management, and it's not the router. 18.04, no problem, in this or other Thinkpad computers. 20.04, massive loss of speed, in this and other Thinkpad computers. I am about to delete 20.04 and "upgrade" to 18.04.