# Ubuntu WiFi connection extremely spotty

Tags: networking

I’m having a problem with my Ubuntu’s WiFi connection. For whatever reason the connection keeps dropping for no reason and the signal strength varies quite a bit. How do I fix this?

Comment: There is no information in the question at all. There can be a ton of reasons for that.

Comment: on Windows this problem was usually related to power save modes of your wifi card, and/or drivers. you can do some research about disabling power save, and if it doesn't work try to update your wifi card drivers

Comment: Please check my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)