# Wireless connection is lost rapidly

Tags: wireless, 22.04, iwlwifi, systemd-networkd

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 with `systemd-networkd` and `netplan` for managing my network.

My connection to the wifi gets lost frequently and reconnects after a while.

None of the solutions I found on the internet, worked for me.

`uname -a`:

```
Linux mypc 5.15.0-50-generic #56-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 20 13:23:26 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`cat /etc/lsb-release`:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
```

`systemd --version`:

```
systemd 249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.6)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +APPARMOR +IMA +SMACK +SECCOMP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +OPENSSL +ACL +BLKID +CURL +ELFUTILS +FIDO2 +IDN2 -IDN +IPTC +KMOD +LIBCRYPTSETUP +LIBFDISK +PCRE2 -PWQUALITY -P11KIT -QRENCODE +BZIP2 +LZ4 +XZ +ZLIB +ZSTD -XKBCOMMON +UTMP +SYSVINIT default-hierarchy=unified
```

`journalctl`:

```
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Got message type=method_return sender=:1.129 destination=:1.0 path=n/a interface=n/a member=n/a cookie=6 reply_cookie=187 signature=n/a error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc dbus-daemon[1085]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc charon[1551]: 05[CFG] joining forecast multicast groups: 224.0.0.1,224.0.0.22,224.0.0.251,224.0.0.252,239.255.255.250
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc charon[1551]: 05[NET] using forecast interface wlo1
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=191 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: State changed: configuring -> configured
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: link_check_ready(): dhcp4:yes ipv4ll:no dhcp6_addresses:no dhcp6_routes:no dhcp6_pd_addresses:no dhcp6_pd_routes:no ndisc_addresses:no ndisc_routes:no
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Received remembered route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: dhcp4_check_ready(): DHCPv4 address and routes are not set.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Received remembered route: dst: 192.168.1.1/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: dhcp4_check_ready(): DHCPv4 address and routes are not set.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.0/24, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: kernel, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.255/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: link, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: broadcast, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Remembering foreign route: dst: 192.168.1.102/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: host, table: local(255), proto: kernel, type: local, nexthop: 0, priority: 0
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-timesyncd[1013]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=190 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: link_check_ready(): dynamic addresses or routes are not configured.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=189 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Remembering updated address: 192.168.1.102/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: permanent
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Configuring route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc charon[1551]: 16[KNL] 192.168.1.102 appeared on wlo1
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Configuring route: dst: 192.168.1.1/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Configuring address: 192.168.1.102/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: link_check_ready(): DHCP4, DHCP6 or IPv4LL is enabled but no dynamic address is assigned yet.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=188 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: State changed: configured -> configuring
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Requesting route: dst: 192.168.1.1/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCP: requested route destination 192.168.1.1/32 is in the assigned network 192.168.1.0/24, ignoring gateway address 192.168.1.1
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Requesting route: dst: n/a, src: n/a, gw: 192.168.1.1, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: global, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Requesting route: dst: 192.168.1.1/32, src: n/a, gw: n/a, prefsrc: 192.168.1.102, scope: link, table: main(254), proto: dhcp, type: unicast, nexthop: 0, priority: 10
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCP: No static routes received from DHCP server.
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Requesting address: 192.168.1.102/24 (valid forever, preferred forever), flags: n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 address 192.168.1.102/24 via 192.168.1.1
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=method_call sender=n/a destination=org.freedesktop.hostname1 path=/org/freedesktop/hostname1 interface=org.freedesktop.hostname1 member=SetHostname cookie=187 reply_cookie=0 signature=sb error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Setting transient hostname: 'dhcppc2'
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc dbus-daemon[1085]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.0' (uid=100 pid=997 comm="/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd " label="unconfined")
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: T1 expires in 1d 11h 59min 59s
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: T2 expires in 2d 15h
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: lease expires in 2d 23h 59min 59s
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: ACK
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Failed to parse domain name, ignoring: Invalid argument
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: REQUEST (requesting)
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: OFFER
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Failed to parse domain name, ignoring: Invalid argument
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: DISCOVER
Oct 13 15:53:24 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: REBOOTED
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: REQUEST (init-reboot)
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=186 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: DHCPv4 client: STARTED on ifindex 3
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Acquiring DHCPv4 lease
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Gained carrier
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=185 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Flags change: +RUNNING
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 completed [id=9 id_str=]
Oct 13 15:53:20 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=184 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=183 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc kernel: wlo1: associated
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Flags change: +LOWER_UP
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: Associated with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc kernel: wlo1: associate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (try 1/3)
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc kernel: wlo1: authenticated
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (SSID='mywifi' freq=2462 MHz)
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc kernel: wlo1: send auth to 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (try 1/3)
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc kernel: wlo1: authenticate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (SSID='mywifi' freq=2462 MHz)
Oct 13 15:53:19 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=9 ssid="mywifi"
Oct 13 15:53:09 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=182 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:09 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=181 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:09 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: rtnl: received non-static neighbor, ignoring.
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: BSSID 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=9 ssid="mywifi" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=00:13:33:f8:98:d2 reason=1 locally_generated=1
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Flags change: -LOWER_UP
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc kernel: wlo1: Connection to AP 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 lost
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=180 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: Sent message type=signal sender=n/a destination=n/a path=/org/freedesktop/network1/link/_33 interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties member=PropertiesChanged cookie=179 reply_cookie=0 signature=sa{sv}as error-name=n/a error-message=n/a
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Started LLDP.
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: LLDP: Started LLDP client
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc systemd-networkd[997]: wlo1: Flags change: +LOWER_UP
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: Associated with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc kernel: wlo1: associated
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc kernel: wlo1: RX AssocResp from 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc kernel: wlo1: associate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (try 1/3)
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc kernel: wlo1: authenticated
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (SSID='mywifi' freq=2462 MHz)
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc kernel: wlo1: send auth to 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (try 1/3)
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc kernel: wlo1: authenticate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2
Oct 13 15:53:08 mypc wpa_supplicant[894]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with 00:13:33:f8:98:d2 (SSID='mywifi' freq=2462 MHz)
```

`lspci -nnkv`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev 73)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
    Memory at d0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number fc-f8-ae-ff-ff-d8-4b-d1
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

`iwconfig`:

```
wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"mywifi"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:13:33:F8:98:D2
          Bit Rate=135 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=47/70  Signal level=-63 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:10   Missed beacon:0
```

`lsmod | grep -i iwl`:

```
iwlmvm                569344  0
mac80211             1253376  1 iwlmvm
iwlwifi               450560  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              974848  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 22.04 as I mentioned in the first line

Comment: Many non Ubuntu products use the 22.04 as well hence my question.

Comment: I added the output of ``cat /etc/lsb-release``

Comment: Part of why I asked is I do not recognize the kernel. Linux a-b-b 5.15.0-50-generic

Comment: Please check my trobleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I already tested them with no luck.