# Wifi problem on 22.10

Tags: wireless, 22.10

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 from Ubuntu 22.04 and at first the wifi was not working but after a reboot it worked. Now it disconnects after a while of it working. It is not a problem with my router since on windows it works fine. It works fine with a hotspot on my phone. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please try my trobleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295