# WiFi drops out for several seconds every few seconds

Tags: networking, wireless, ping

I have a strange "high ping spikes" problem

I always have a ping of 8-20ms but from time to time (approx. 1x per minute but very differently) the internet on my work computer freezes for a few seconds
then my ping looks something like this:

```
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=73 ttl=109 time=8.87 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=74 ttl=109 time=8.93 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=75 ttl=109 time=10.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=76 ttl=109 time=4482 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=77 ttl=109 time=3462 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=78 ttl=109 time=2439 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=79 ttl=109 time=1415 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=80 ttl=109 time=392 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=81 ttl=109 time=8.72 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=82 ttl=109 time=8.56 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=83 ttl=109 time=8.71 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=84 ttl=109 time=8.61 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=85 ttl=109 time=44.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=86 ttl=109 time=8.76 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=87 ttl=109 time=8.77 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=88 ttl=109 time=8.76 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=89 ttl=109 time=8.72 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=90 ttl=109 time=8.84 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=91 ttl=109 time=9.88 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=92 ttl=109 time=8.74 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=93 ttl=109 time=9.38 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=94 ttl=109 time=9.19 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=95 ttl=109 time=5363 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=96 ttl=109 time=4356 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=97 ttl=109 time=3333 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=98 ttl=109 time=2305 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=99 ttl=109 time=1288 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=100 ttl=109 time=264 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=101 ttl=109 time=8.92 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=102 ttl=109 time=8.78 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=103 ttl=109 time=8.73 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=104 ttl=109 time=9.23 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=105 ttl=109 time=8.73 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=106 ttl=109 time=8.76 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=107 ttl=109 time=8.72 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=108 ttl=109 time=8.91 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=109 ttl=109 time=8.74 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=110 ttl=109 time=8.75 ms
```

Info:

- I have Kubuntu 22.04 LTS
- I have fiber optic connection since yesterday ... before that my network was very unstable. So I don't know if the problem was there before and I just didn't notice it or if it's just since the switch
- My computer is connected to a Fritz!Box via WLAN
- The problem occurs with two different WLAN sticks (different companies/models)
- The problem does NOT occur on other computers with Kubuntu 22.04 LTS (two computers, two laptops, also over the same Wifi)

System:

- Kubuntu 22.04 LTS (new installation used to be a 20.04 LTS ... Upgrades: 20.04 LTS >> 21.04 >> 21.10 >> 22.04 LTS)
- 128GB RAM --- AMD Ryzen 5950x --- Radeon RX 6600 XT

what I've tried so far:

- I have already changed wifi.powersave from 3 to 2 in /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf

The following logs do not show any entries at the times in question:

- route
- journalctl -f
- journalctl -fu NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
- journalctl -fu NetworkManager.service

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295 and also: https://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-features/33228-wi-fi-ping-spikes-causes-and-fixes Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ok "sudo iw reg set DE" seems to work
I have now tested for about 5 minutes and only have drops from 1000ms (and much less frequently)
will now enter the "DE" in the /etc/default/crda and restart ... let's see

Comment: ok, this seems to dosnt help at all ... it dropt again about 5000-9000ms repeatedly

Comment: how can i check if my Kubuntu goes off-channel to perform a background scan or an OBSS scan ?

Comment: Did you set a fixed channel in the 5 gHz segment? Are there any clues here: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp`

Comment: i tryed a fixed channel on 2,4 and 5 GHz ... no fixes
and "sudo dmesg | grep wlp" echos nothing
In addition, all other devices work perfectly, which is why I rule out a router-side wifi problem

Comment: What is your wireless interface if not wlp-something? `iwconfig` `sudo dmesg | grep whatever_you_find`

Comment: wlxdc4ef40a4118  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Lilie1966"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: B0:F2:08:XX:XX:XX   
          Bit Rate=300 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1071  Invalid misc:3126   Missed beacon:0

Comment: [    8.352138] rt2800usb 7-4:1.0 wlxdc4ef40a4118: renamed from wlan0

Comment: no response ?
is this right with the comments ?
or is this thread "dead" and i need a new one ?

Comment: Did you rename the 2.4 and 5 gHz segments of your router so the wireless sticks to just the 5 gHz band?