# Wifi connection loops on ubuntu

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I'm no expert in networking so I think I need a helping hand.

I installed ubuntu 22.04 yesterday and connected to my home wifi without any problems (I think, because I quickly switched to a wired connection), then today I am at another house and I cannot connect to the wifi here.

When I insert the wifi password and try to connect, it gets stuck in connecting. Upon seeing this I ran `nmcli m` and attempted to connect again, and got this:

```
wlp6s0: using connection 'MyNetworkName'
wlp6s0: connecting (prepare)
Networkmanager is now in the 'connecting' state
wlp6s0: connecting (configuring)
wlp6s0: connecting (need authentication)
wlp6s0: connecting (prepare)
wlp6s0: connecting (configuring)
MyNetworkName: connection profile changed
wlp6s0: connecting (getting IP configuration)
Connectivity is now 'limited'
Connectivity is now 'full'
wlp6s0: connection failed
Networkmanager is now in the 'disconnected' state
wlp6s0: disconnected
Connectivity is now 'limited'
Connectivity is now 'none'

wlp6s0: using connection 'MyNetworkName'
wlp6s0: connecting (prepare)
Networkmanager is now in the 'connecting' state
wlp6s0: connecting (configuring)
wlp6s0: connecting (need authentication)
wlp6s0: connecting (prepare)
wlp6s0: connecting (configuring)
MyNetworkName: connection profile changed
wlp6s0: connecting (getting IP configuration)
Connectivity is now 'limited'
Connectivity is now 'full'
wlp6s0: connection failed
Networkmanager is now in the 'disconnected' state
wlp6s0: disconnected
Connectivity is now 'limited'
Connectivity is now 'none'
```

And this behaviour loops forever as far as I know. While the connection is 'full' I can access websites normally, although the wifi icon still indicates connecting, but this only lasts for about 30 seconds.

All other devices work normally in this network and what's more, when I create a wifi hotspot from my smartphone (which is connected to the same network) I can connect to it just fine. This makes me think there is some sort of incompatibility between my computer's settings and the router's, but I don't know where to start so if anyone could at least give me some pointers, that would be great, thanks! If any nore logs are required please tell me and I will quickly get them and post them here.

Comment: Please consider my troubleshooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you posted I was already not in the network giving me these problems. When I return, if I get the same problems I'll be sure check this out.