# Unstable wifi connection after Ubuntu 23.10 update

Tags: networking, wireless, 23.10

since i updated ubuntu to 23.10 I've notice some problems with wifi connection. Randomly the wifi disconnects without any visual feedback, and then connects on the next second.
I've noticed this by being in the middle of a online meeting and freeze for about a second and then comes back to normal. Also some applications give me the message of being offline for a second and then all normal.

Can anyone guide me to how i can figure out the problem? i have the following report of info related to wifi.

Something interesting that i saw on the logs is this event

```
[ 4719.217690] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> for auth to <MAC 
'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
```

Full logs

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Nov 2023 09:53 WET +0000

Booted last: 16 Nov 2023 00:00 WET +0000

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.5.0-10-generic #10-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Oct 13 13:49:38 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu on Xorg

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0408:30d4 Quanta Computer, Inc. USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1532:005c Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Elite
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1724416  3 mt76,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               73728  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
ledtrig_audio          12288  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,asus_wmi
sparse_keymap          12288  1 asus_wmi
platform_profile       12288  1 asus_wmi
cfg80211             1314816  4 mt76,mac80211,mt7921_common,mt76_connac_lib
wmi_bmof               12288  0
libarc4                12288  1 mac80211
video                  73728  2 asus_wmi,amdgpu
wmi                    40960  4 video,asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet [hidden IP] brd [hidden IP] scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp1s0
       valid_lft 3560sec preferred_lft 3560sec
    inet6 [hidden IP] scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 474sec preferred_lft 474sec
    inet6 [hidden IP] scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 474sec preferred_lft 474sec
    inet6 [hidden IP] scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"NOS-1337-5"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.5 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>   
          Bit Rate=117 Mb/s   Tx-Power=3 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=37/70  Signal level=-73 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

default via [hidden IP] dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp src [hidden IP] metric 600 
[hidden IP] dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
[hidden IP] dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src [hidden IP] metric 600 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver [hidden IP]
options edns0 trust-ad
search home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root        1182       1  0 08:27 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         MEDIATEK Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         mt7921e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-10-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               ____010000-20230526130958
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.2/0000:01:00.0/net/wlp1s0
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:01:00.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       wlp1s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     NOS-1337-5
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       [hidden IP]
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     117 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.MESH:                   no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.IBSS-RSN:               no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         [hidden IP]
IP4.GATEWAY:                            [hidden IP]
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = [hidden IP], mt = 600
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = [hidden IP], nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = [hidden IP], nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
IP4.DNS[1]:                             [hidden IP]
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = [hidden IP]
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_client_identifier = 01:<MAC 'wlp1s0' [IF1]>
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = [hidden IP]
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        domain_name_servers = [hidden IP]
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        expiry = 1700131996
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        host_name = NOSdrive\044routertecnico
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        ip_address = [hidden IP]
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       routers = [hidden IP]
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.254.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         [hidden IP]
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         [hidden IP]
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         [hidden IP]
IP6.GATEWAY:                            [hidden IP]
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2a01:14:104:2ba0::/64, nh = ::, mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 2a01:14:104:2ba0::/64, nh = fe80::6666:24ff:fe30:922f, mt = 605
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = [hidden IP], mt = 600
IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = [hidden IP], mt = 20600
IP6.DNS[1]:                             [hidden IP]
IP6.DNS[2]:                             [hidden IP]
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   [hidden]

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         p2p-dev-wlp1s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi-p2p
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifiP2P
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         (unknown)
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /virtual/device/placeholder/1
GENERAL.PATH:                           --
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --       

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-04af3578-a519-4126-821a-310459b07f9e.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-2adfcbc1-af1a-4547-b858-9133d8d862ab.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-403586de-5187-40a2-95e1-670a7882b681.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-633d8198-4ec7-4cff-8690-d883254e9182.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-7d9ef67e-3d8c-4c90-bf61-8f5120c4a367.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /etc/netplan/90-NM-7dbd239c-6c66-4521-9769-bc0586426738.yaml: Permission denied
grep: /lib/netplan/00-network-manager-all.yaml: Permission denied

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

wlp1s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.5 GHz (Channel 100)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      2   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      4   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.22 GHz (Channel 44)
      2   APs on   Frequency:5.5 GHz (Channel 100)


##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko.zst
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       6.5.0-10-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-10-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko.zst
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       6.5.0-10-generic SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[ 3137.765520] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 3137.787885] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 3137.820991] wlp1s0: associated
[ 3176.709298] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 3176.871131] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 3176.904428] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 3176.906760] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 3176.908892] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 3176.931051] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 3176.962249] wlp1s0: associated
[ 3177.006336] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4524.867448] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4525.053141] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4525.081501] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4525.083800] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4525.086975] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4525.108275] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[ 4525.141661] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4564.060891] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4564.238531] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4564.271737] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4564.274066] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4564.276543] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4564.298261] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 4564.330639] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4564.348652] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4641.303318] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4641.465702] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4641.498835] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4641.501233] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4641.503171] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4641.526653] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[ 4641.559683] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4680.444729] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4680.628217] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4680.655736] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4680.658065] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4680.660267] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4680.682165] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 4680.712072] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4680.758597] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4719.217690] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4719.383375] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4719.416526] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4719.418861] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4719.421239] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4719.443123] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[ 4719.474558] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4758.354509] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4758.485699] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4758.514196] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4758.516512] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4758.518090] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4758.540809] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 4758.573913] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4758.685466] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4835.459760] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4835.636362] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 4835.669460] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4835.671879] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4835.679453] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 4835.696291] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[ 4835.729309] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4874.668576] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4874.839755] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 4874.867454] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4874.870276] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 4874.876082] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 4874.894530] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 4874.926689] wlp1s0: associated
[ 4874.945750] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 5105.518225] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 5105.679828] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]>
[ 5105.712886] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 5105.715305] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 5105.717708] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (try 1/3)
[ 5105.739541] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=1)
[ 5105.772670] wlp1s0: associated
[ 5144.738250] wlp1s0: disconnect from AP <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC1]> for new auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 5144.915972] wlp1s0: authenticate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>
[ 5144.949122] wlp1s0: send auth to <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 5144.951446] wlp1s0: authenticated
[ 5144.957726] wlp1s0: associate with <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (try 1/3)
[ 5144.976266] wlp1s0: RX ReassocResp from <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]> (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[ 5145.007081] wlp1s0: associated
[ 5145.042813] wlp1s0: Limiting TX power to 30 (30 - 0) dBm as advertised by <MAC 'NOS-1337-5' [AC3]>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: You have two access points named NOS-1337-5. I suspect that your wireless device is roaming among them. Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364239/tp-link-usb-wireless-adapter-keep-losing-data-every-several-minutes-without-disc/1364295#1364295 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.